# certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --dns-digitalocean-credentials

Tags: linux, ubuntu, letsencrypt, certbot, digital-ocean

Trying to execute this command

```
sudo certbot certonly --dns-digitalocean --dns-digitalocean-credentials ~/.secrets/digitalocean.ini -d "*.example.com" --preferred-challenges dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

i get this error: 
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --dns-digitalocean-credentials

The operating system my web server runs on is: **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**

**certbot --version** output: certbot 0.31.0

And the dashes in command "--dns-digitalocean-credentials" entered correctly.

Also dns plugin installed too:

```
python3-certbot-dns-digitalocean/xenial 0.23.0-2ubuntu0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1
```

Help solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I received the `unrecognized arguments: --dns-digitalocean-credentials` error even with Certbot version 0.40.0 (default deb package for Ubuntu 20.04). The man page describes `--dns-digitalocean-credentials` but it isn't recognized.

The solution is to install via a snap:

```
sudo apt purge -y certbot
sudo snap install --classic certbot
sudo snap set certbot trust-plugin-with-root=ok
sudo snap install certbot-dns-digitalocean
```

As of this posting, this yields Certbot 1.9.0, which worked well to generate and install my wildcard TLS certificate.

You didn't ask, but here is the full Certbot command I used:

```
sudo certbot run --domain example.com --domain '*.example.com' --authenticator dns-digitalocean --installer apache --dns-digitalocean-credentials /root/.certbot.token --dns-digitalocean-propagation-seconds 60 --agree-tos --keep-until-expiring --redirect --hsts --uir --email webmaster@example.com --no-eff-email
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that automated DNS certificate renewal methods were only introduced in versions of certbot later than 0.31.0.

The current version is 1.3.0-5, but this hasn't found its way into your Ubuntu release. I don't know that for sure, but I do know that it hasn't yet made it into Debian Buster which I use.

I switched to [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh). I found this at least as easy to implement as certbot and more transparent. You just need to [`export` your DigitalOcean key into a variable](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/dnsapi#20-use-digitalocean-api-native) before running `acme.sh`.

Comment: I don't know how "transparent" acme.sh is. I found the [Apache/Nginx instructions confusing to the point of not knowing what to do](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/issues/2953).